# Why is overriding postRegister in Laravel AuthController not working?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, overriding

I am adapting the out-of-the-box AuthController in Laravel 5.2 to suit my needs.  When registering a new user, do not wish for the new user to be logged in automatically.  I have read that by overriding the postRegister method from the RedirectsUsers trait in AuthController, you can alter the work flow.  So my AuthController looks like this:

```
 class AuthController extends Controller {
   ...
   protected function create(array $data) {
   }

   public function postRegister(Request $request) {
     $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
     if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
     }
     $this->create($request->all());
     return redirect($this->redirectPath());
   }
 }
```

However, my postRegister method appears to be ignored.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: as the below answer is demonstrating, the default auth does not create a route to `postRegister`, it creates one to `register`. `php artisan route:list` to see what method the routes are pointing to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to overwrite register function

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        // Removed to prevent auto login
        //Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));
        $this->create($request->all());


        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Can Celik this does override (should have checked the route list).

Comment: I was overriding `postRegister()`, lost 3 hours untill I saw your answer

Comment: I was doing the the same Matias :)