# how to redirect with info message after register or login in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to redirect **with info message** after register or login in laravel 5.7, but I cant find the solution

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';

protected function redirectTo()
{
    return redirect()->route('projects')->with('info', 'welcome');
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a session with flash message before redirect other url:

Session::flash('error','message');

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct - but how are you displaying the flash message in your view?

```
@if ($info = session('info'))
  <p>{{ $info }}</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
return redirect()->with(['success' => 'your message']);
```

In your view blade file

```
@if (session('success')) 
   {{ session('success') }} 
@endif
```

Comment: the redirectTo() method should return a string

Answer (score 0):

With your path set above as;

```
protected $redirectTo = '/projects';
```

Go to your controllers path /Auth/RegisterController.php, override the register function as [Chan Celik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095548/why-is-overriding-postregister-in-laravel-authcontroller-not-working) posted. I have simply extended on his idea. I hope this helps someone in future

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    // Removed to prevent auto login
    //Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));
    
    $this->create($request->all());


    return redirect($this->redirectTo)->with('info', 'welcome');
}
```